# sort arrays in multidimensional array associative to the others

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting

I've three associative arrays with the same length. These arrays are in a multidimensional array. Something like this:

```
var multi_array = [];
var array_a     = [2,3,4,1,5];
var array_b     = [0,7,9,8,6];
var array_c     = ['A','D','B','A','E'];

multi_array     = [array_a, array_b, array_c];
```

[image]

So if I try to sort multi_array like this:

```
multi_array[0].sort(function(a,b){
                        if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){
                            return a > b ? 1 : -1;
                        }
                        return a - b;
                    });
```

It only sorts the first array.

[image]

I want, that the other arrays get sorted by the same indecies depends of the sorted one like this:

[image]

Comment: So, you want to sort the first array of the `multi_array`, then sort the others based on the index of the first. For example, `array_a[3] = 1` and `array_b[3] = 8`, after sorting, `array_a[0]` is now holding `1` then `array_b[0]` should be holding `8` ? Correct?

Comment: What do you mean by 'get sorted by the same indecies depends of the sorted one'?

Comment: @CalvinNunes yeah, that's exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest code, but it prints your answer:

```js
var array_a = [2, 3, 4, 1, 5];
var array_b = [0, 7, 9, 8, 6];
var array_c = ['A', 'D', 'B', 'A', 'E'];

// get indices from array_a sorted
var len = array_a.length;
var indices = new Array(len);
for (var i = 0; i < array_a.length; ++i) indices[i] = i;
indices.sort(function(a, b) {
  return array_a[a] < array_a[b] ? -1 : array_a[a] > array_a[b] ? 1 : 0;
});

// sorted array_b and sorted_array_c
var sorted_array_a = [];
var sorted_array_b = [];
var sorted_array_c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
  sorted_array_a.push(array_a[indices[i]]);
  sorted_array_b.push(array_b[indices[i]]);
  sorted_array_c.push(array_c[indices[i]])
}

var multi_array = [sorted_array_a, sorted_array_b, sorted_array_c]


console.log(multi_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort each array in the multi_array

```js
var multi_array = [];
var array_a     = [2,3,4,1,5]; //1,2,3,4,5 0:1,1:2,2:3,3:0,4:4 
var array_b     = [0,7,9,8,6]; //8,0,7,9,6
var array_c     = ['A','D','B','A','E'];

multi_array     = [array_a, array_b, array_c];

// clone the first array_a
var multi_temp = multi_array[0].slice(0);

// sort the clone
multi_temp.sort(function(a,b){
                     if(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)){
                          return a > b ? 1 : -1;
                     }
                     return a - b;
                    });

// get the algorithm of key for sorting
var id = [];
multi_array[0].forEach((val, i) => {
 id[i] = multi_temp.indexOf(val);
} );

// and apply the algorithm in the multi_array
multi_array = multi_array.map(item => {
 var temp = [];
 id.forEach((val, i) => {
  temp[val] = item[i];
 });
 return temp;
});

console.log(multi_array);
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, please re-read it and also read the comments of the question. (Check his desired output also), He wants 1st array sorted, the others should follow the 1st just by index, not by sort order